# cast and left functions in Athena

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

cast and convert function works as expected in Athena:

```
SELECT code_2 as mydate,  cast( code_2 as varchar) from some_table
```

but how do I extract 8 leftmost characters? This throws an error:

```
SELECT code_2 as mydate,  left(cast( code_2 as varchar),8) as date from some_table
```

Here is the error:

> extraneous input 'left' expecting

Comment: just FYI, right and left are not supported in Presto. use lpad, rpad, substr instead.

`lpad(code_2,8,' ')` is the equivalent of `left(code_2,8)`

https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/string.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting directly to `VARCHAR(8)`:

```
SELECT
    code_2 AS mydate,
    CAST(code_2 AS VARCHAR(8))
FROM some_table;
```

I have never used Athena, but the documentation implies that this should work.  This trick works on Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

If `code_2` is a string, then use `substr()`:

```
select code_2 as mydate, substr(code_2, 1, 8) as date
from some_table;
```

If `code_2` is a date, then use the appropriate date function:

```
select code_2 as mydate,
       date_format(code_2, '%Y-%m-%d') as date
from some_table;
```

Use the appropriate function for the data type.  Do not convert dates to strings when there are built-in functions that do exactly what you want and give you more control.